# Spring Boot Actuator hides property values in env endpoint

Tags: configuration, spring-boot

My problem is, that my Spring-Boot Actuator endpoint for `env` actually replaces some properties with starts like this:

```
"applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/application.properties]" : {
    "rest.baseurl" : "http://85.214.247.80:9912",
    "projectKey" : "******",
```

And I have no clue why. I did not have any hint in my application thats he should hide it. I guess there is some heuristic to hide it based on the property name.

any Ideas how to avoid the masking?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default the `/env` endpoint will hide the value of any property with a key that, ignoring case, ends with `password`, `secret`, or `key`. You can customize this using the `endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize` property. The value of this property should be a comma-separated list of suffixes or regexes to match against property names. For example, if you don't care about keys ending in `key` you could set it to:

```
endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize=password,secret
```

This is what the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.actuator.management.endpoint.configprops.keys-to-sanitize) says:

> endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize=password,secret,key,token,.*credentials.*,vcap_services
>
> Keys that should be sanitized. Keys can be simple strings that the property ends with or regex expressions.

Comment: This is no longer true for Spring Boot 3. For Spring Boot 3 the correct answer is the one by Amit Garg above.

Answer (score 42):

Now from Spring boot version 3, by default the value of all properties are hidden.

To display the value in /env endpoint, below configuration needs to be added in application.properties file.

```
management.endpoint.env.show-values=ALWAYS
```

Valid values for the Property is as below

```
ALWAYS
NEVER
WHEN_AUTHORIZED
```

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned previously that by default Sprint Boot 3+ has all the values hidden for both the env and config prop endpoint, you can read more about this in the [migration guide here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#actuator-endpoints-sanitization).

To enable you will need to set the following:

```
management.endpoint.env.show-values=ALWAYS
management.endpoint.configprops.show-values=ALWAYS
```

Or:

```
management.endpoint.env.show-values=WHEN_AUTHORIZED
management.endpoint.configprops.show-values=WHEN_AUTHORIZED
```

However, this will show all values **including passwords, credentials, etc.** that were previously masked.

To be able to mask them again you can [read this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32156#issuecomment-1470804473), which also includes the details of the original change that made the behaviour change.

Comment: Thanks for your implementation in the ticket. Can you paste it also here?  It can help many people to find it.

Answer (score 5):

For Spring Boot 3, put in pom.xml `management.endpoint.env.show-values=ALWAYS`

Answer (score 4):

The property to set now is `management.endpoint.env.keys-to-sanitize`. To reveal all properties just set it to nothing, e.g. `management.endpoint.env.keys-to-sanitize=`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as @Andy Wilkinson mention. But you will see `"endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize"` property with value `"password,secret"` in the `applicationConfig` section of `/env` endpoint.

To avoid this you can set the property using code as well:

```
public class MyApp {
    @Autowired
    private EnvironmentEndpoint envEndPnt;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
         envEndPnt.setKeysToSanitize("password","secret");
    } 
}
```

So once all the initializations are done and the `initApplication` is called you will have the `EnvironmentEndPoint` to which you set the property manually.