# Spring Boot Admin Server 3.x hides the values of the configuration properties view

Tags: spring-boot-admin

it seems that since version 3 of Spring Boot Admin Server the configuration values from discovered Spring Boot Apps in the view "Configuration Properties" are hidden (******). Is there way to show the config values?

Comment: It is not Spring Boot Admin hiding the values, but Spring Boot 3. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75749847/7502730

Please check the Spring Boot migration guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#actuator-endpoints-sanitization.

Comment: @StephanKöninger Thanks for the hint - now the values are no more hidden.